# Eslint перестал исправлять ошибки

Tags: javascript, webpack

После обновления пакетов eslint перестал работать autofix, он находит и подчеркивает ошибки, но сам не корректирует. Я использую eslint c webpack 4

```
 rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 'eslint-loader?{fix:true}',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            enforce: 'pre',
        },
```

Comment: ... он просто перестал делать ошибки (с)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в eslint-loader при апгрейде на версию 2.1.1

Решение вернуться на версию 2.1.0 и ждать когда пофиксят